Creating events on Google Room Resources thru API not allowed on other Workspace Accounts
I have a solution where you connect your companys Google Workspace to our solution and get these scopes.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

We can thru our service add Events to calenders they connect. For user calenders this works great. We can add a meeting with above permission on the endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calenderId/events
Now to the problem. In the list of accounts we also have room resources that have an id looking something like this "c_asdasdasdasdicrql2isb1ocs@resource.calendar.google.com"
When using the same endpoint to create these Events we get an error saying "GaxiosError: You need to have writer access to this calendar". This annoys the heck out of me. Checking the api documentation there is no scope defining for resources specifically.
I think I have a workaround where you add our Service Account Client ID to the customers Third-party apps as trusted. But this removes the cleanness of connecting our account with just a click more or less. Now having to copy strange strange service account email and adding it manually creates the possibility for so many issues.
Anyone that has worked with this or found a solution with resources bookings.

95% of what you have said is all statements.  What exactly the issue and what is your question?

Not really following Linda what you mean. Staring from around middle “now to the problem”. We can’t book meeting in resource  calendars. Then we get an error.
However I will now close this because it seems like this was a bug at google side yesterday. Trying today with the exact same setup the issue has disappeared.
